# search equals width LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic list of lists, trying to determine if there are already five equal numbers in each list.
If not find equals in lists, then add list into lists
this code work but I like learn more about linq.

how can  do this using LINQ.
thank you

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int n1 = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
        int n2 = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
        int n3 = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
        int n4 = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
        int n5 = (int)numericUpDown5.Value;
        int n6 = (int)numericUpDown6.Value;
        int n7 = (int)numericUpDown7.Value;
        int n8 = (int)numericUpDown8.Value;
        int n9 = (int)numericUpDown9.Value;
        int n10 = (int)numericUpDown10.Value;
        int n11 = (int)numericUpDown11.Value;
        int n12 = (int)numericUpDown12.Value;
            list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(n1);
            list.Add(n2);
            list.Add(n3);
            list.Add(n4);
            list.Add(n5);
            list.Add(n6);
            list.Add(n7);
            list.Add(n8);
            list.Add(n9);
            list.Add(n10);
            list.Add(n11);
            list.Add(n12);
            if (data.Count == 0)
                data.Add(list);
            else
            {
                int l = data.Count;
                bool eq =false;
                for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
                {
                    int count = 0;
                    foreach (int n in list)
                    {
                        if (data[i].IndexOf(n) != -1)
                            ++count;
                        if (count == 5)
                        {
                            eq = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (eq == true)
                        break;
                }
                if (eq == false)
                    data.Add(list);
                else
                {
                    // do nothing
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: What your trying to achieve is not that clear. If I understand your code : if one of the existing list contains : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and new list contains [1, 1, 1, 1, 1] it won't be added. Is this an error, or wanted ? I thought you wanted "5 different numbers in common".

Comment: eg if data[0] contains [1,2,3,4,5,6] and data[1] is[1,2,3,4,7,8] is OK data[2] is [2,3,4,5,6,10] this is not OK because data[0] contains five equals numbers

Comment: But the case I gave should return OK, or not OK ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus The case you gave is OK, per Rock's clarification comment.  If overlap of 5+, then NOT OK, else OK.

Answer (score 0):

> trying to determine if there are already five equal numbers in each list. If not, then add them  into lists

You can combine [`Enumerable.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) and loops, for example:

```
int n1 = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
foreach(List<int> list in data)
{
    int count = list.Count(i => i == n1);
    while(count++ < 5)
        list.Add(n1);
}
```

Comment: As I understood, the problem is : I have a list of lists. And I want to compare them to a new list. If no one of the existing list contains five number in common with the new list, add the new list to the existing list of lists. Clear, no ? I think your code doesn't resolve that problem, but I may have not understood well.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: You may be right, i simply don't know and wait until OP proves you right, then i'll delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `Intersect` and `Count` extension methods.

something like

```
var exist = false;
foreach (var existingList in data) {
  if (existingList.Intersect(list).Count() >=5) {
    exist = true;
    break;
}

if (!exist) data.Add(list);
```

But depending on the size of your lists, this will be far less performant, as the "check for intersects >= 5" will intersect all data of the lists.

Comment: shouldnt it be `Intersect`? Also you would need `Count()`

Comment: :) but which do you think will perform better? I suppose yours than Tim's

Comment: @nawfal I think they don't do the same. As the question is "not that clear", we may have not understood the same.

Comment: Yes thats right too.. Had not checked the code but just the O(scope) :)

Comment: So it is better to use own code as a linq, because I break the loop when find five equals?

Comment: @Rock It might be, but see my comment to your question. This problem won't happen with my code (if it's a problem !). Depending of the size of your list, choose the linq one (more concise / readable) or a more performant one. The lists must be quite big to see a meaningfull difference.

Answer (score 0):

**[EDIT] - please see the [UPDATE] below**

I believe that your current code should look like:

```
...
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    //int count = 0;
    foreach (int n in list)
    {
...
```

Anyway, to answer your question (if I understood correctly what you want to achieve) you may use this:

```
class Program
{
    static List<List<int>> data;
    static List<int> list;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data = new List<List<int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            list = new List<int>();
            list.Add(1);
            list.Add(2);
            list.Add(1);

            var result = data
                .Union(new[]{list})
                .SelectMany(j => j)
                .GroupBy(j => j)
                .Select(j => new { j.Key, j })
                .Where(j => j.j.Count() > 4);

            if (result.Count() == 0)
                data.Add(list);

        }
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

Ok, I think I understood what you want to achieve: if there are no other lists in `data` that have at least 5 elements in common with the `list`, the `list` should be added to the `data`, which is a `List<List<int>>`.

```
var result = data.Any(i => i.Intersect(list).Count() > 4);
if(!result)
    data.Add(list);
```

Comment: Where do you do a comparison between existing lists and the new list ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I use `Union` to evaluate the result set if the list would be added.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code you've posted, I think the solution is:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
List<List<int>> data = new List<List<int>>();

if (data.All(l => l.Intersect(list).Count() < 5))
    data.Add(list);
```